# how to pass console.log value to protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, screenshot

can someone, please, advise on where to seek a solution to the following problem:

I have a code that console.logs some values, but they are not imported into protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter's report.

how to pass those values into the report as they are visible in the log

I'm running protractor against angular app

**my code and terminal output**

[image: my code and terminal output]

**my report output**

[image]

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    captureTimeout: 120000,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

**protractor.conf.js**

```
const HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
  dest: './e2e/test_results/stream',
  filename: 'test-results.html',
  reportOnlyFailedSpecs: false,
  captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true,
  showQuickLinks: true,
  reportFailedUrl: true
});...

  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
```

any other reporters can accommodate that?

Link to Github issue: https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter/issues/123

Comment: Can you paste `karma` configuration? `protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter` is for taking screenshots. Are you using any other reporter by any chance?

Comment: protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter is not only for taking screenshots it does save the report into HTML format which I need. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter 
also, I'm going to add karma.conf.js in the question (not sure if its helpful at all or not)

Comment: also i have jasmine-spec-reporter, but that's what i see in terminal

Comment: I'll link to related GitHub issue here, for completeness: https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter/issues/123

Comment: thank you @MichalLison, that's mine also :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at 'Extra configuration summary items (optional)' section at 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter

Basically you need to create report at end of execution with all data you need to be added using above configuration.

Comment: Also look at lines that are getting added to report and see if you can provide data using same way

Comment: do you have/know of any practical example I can refer to? (google) did not help :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add it in the Report Title when you define the reporter like this:

```
var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
 reportTitle: "Test Report for app" + appNameUsedTrimmed
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, I have multiple log lines to get to the report